# Считать пробел в консоле С++.

Tags: windows, потоки-данных, консоль, visual-studio, c++

Я считываю символ который ввел пользователь.Выглядит это так:

```
char temp=' ';
cout <<"Введите любойсимвол"<<endl;      
cin>>temp;
```

Проблема в том, что это работает со всеми символами, кроме пробела. Когда ввожу пробел ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как считать пробел в консоли?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [`cin.get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Но, возникла другая проблема cin.get() считывает всё, в том числе и перевод строки. У меня просто этот код на самом деле находится в цикле, и эти символы присваиваются элементам массива. А сin.get() получается, что после того, как пользователь введёт символ и нажмёт энтер, то сначала в соответствующий элемент массива будет записан символ, который ввёл пользователь, а в следующий элемент массива будет записан символ перехода на новую строку. Не ту ли какой нибудь функции, которая бы читала пробелы, но не читала бы символы перехода на новую строку, табуляцию и т.д.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Нету. Но вы ведь знаете, что пользователь нажал Enter и тем самым добавил в поток `'\n'`?

1. Вы можете просто считать его (и убедиться, что это именно `'\n'`)
2. Вы можете применить `ignore` (что-нибудь наподобие `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`)
3. Вы можете сказать `fflush(stdin)`

Comment: Спасибо. То, что надо.